# Error in Couldn't find a package.json file during vuepress-Travis CI construction

Tags: travis-ci, yarnpkg

What can I do?
Here is the code for the part where the problem occurs

```
error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/home/travis/build/comter1/document"
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
The command "yarn document:build" exited with 1.
$ yarn cname
yarn run v1.22.4
error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/home/travis/build/comter1/document"
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
The command "yarn cname" exited with 1.
cache.2
store build cache
Done. Your build exited with 1
```

Comment: Maybe create a package.json file?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing following in cname.sh file:

```
echo 'comter1.github.io/document/' > document/.vuepress/dist/CNAME
```

to

```
echo 'comter1.github.io/document/' > ./.vuepress/dist/CNAME
```